# Dark theme / with hooks

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

Hello I have a custom hook to define my theme

code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = usePersistedState('light');
  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme(theme.type === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light');
  };
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={toggleTheme}>a</button>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
```

and here is my hook:

```
import { darkTheme, lightTheme } from '../themes/index';

function usePersistedState(key) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
    switch (key) {
      case 'dark':
        return darkTheme;
      case 'light':
        return lightTheme;
      default:
        return lightTheme;
    }
  });
  console.log(state);
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(state.type));
  }, [key, state]);

  return [state, setState];
}

export default usePersistedState;
```

basically every time my state changes I save it to local storage, but for some reason it only works the first time

when I try to change my theme the second time I do not enter my switch

edit:

[image]

as i show in the gif the first time i get an object because i enter my switch, but when i try to change the theme i get only a text cuz i dont enter my switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument you provide to `useState` will apply **only** on the first render. 
On the next renders, what you provide to `setState` function will be applied (you provide *'light'* or *'dark'*, so state value will be *'light'* or *'dark'*) 
 
For your use case, in which you want the switch case to run every state change, [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) is a better option than useState (in my opinion).

```
import { useReducer } from 'react';
import { darkTheme, lightTheme } from '../themes/index';


function usePersistedState(key) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, null, getTheme(key)); // first argument is the reducer function. second argument is the initial state. third argument is an init function (for complex initialization)

  const reducer = (state, action) => { // this will run on every state change (on every dispatch call)
    return getTheme(action.type)();
  }

  const getTheme = (themeType) => () => {
    switch (themeType) {
      case 'dark':
        return darkTheme;
      case 'light':
        return lightTheme;
      default:
        return lightTheme;
    }
  }

  console.log(state);
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('themeType', JSON.stringify(state));
  }, [state]);

  return [state, dispatch];
}

export default usePersistedState;
```

And from your component you call dispatch like so:

```
export default function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = usePersistedState('light');
  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme(theme.type === 'light' ? {type: 'dark'} : {type: 'light'});
  };
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={toggleTheme}>a</button>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
```

Comment: I'm a little confused :(

basically i would need if there was no value in the storage key would return the theme light
and be able to save when the theme is dark or lgiht
you could help me?

Comment: i'll try to help you out. what is state.type? is it the theme object?

Comment: this is the name of the theme:

export const darkTheme = {
  type: 'dark',
  colors: {
    primary: '# 222',
    secondary: '# DF2935',

    background: '# 333',
    text: '#fff',
  },
};

Comment: that way I would have to import my themes into my custom hook and my app

Comment: @MykonSpt For your use case, useReducer is better than useState. check my updated answer

Comment: thanks, i try and got this error: Cannot access 'reducer' before initialization on :  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, reducer(null, { type: key }));

Comment: @MykonSpt I updated my answer, now it doesn't use the reducer before initialization

Comment: I tried and have the same problem : const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, getTheme(key));

Comment: @MykonSpt , I have updated my answer again. It works with react version 16.12, if your version is different and it's not working, let me know your version

Comment: I really managed to do that, but I'm breaking my head
because that way I can't save the type in my localstorage or I can't save the theme

Comment: You are right, the key in local storage is always 'light' and the value is 'light' or 'dark'. My approach is to use more generic key like 'themeType' and the value will be the theme itself. (that way, at any single time you have only one theme saved in local storage). See the implementation in my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add the object wrapper on the toogle with { type: ... }

```
const toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme({type: theme.type === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'});
};
```